# $page=$_GET['page'] not assigning values from URL parameters page.

Tags: php, pagination

I have trouble recieving and re using the variable i send through a GET varible.

URl parameter "page"  is not assigning values through $_GET['page'].GET is not passing any value to $page vairable.
no of pagination link create are correct but when i click on them post does not changes it shows only first two posts. But my database consist six post 2 in each page mean 3 pages.

```
   <?php 
    require_once('inc/header.php'); 

    $no_of_posts = 2;

    if(isset($_Get['page'])){

        $page=$_Get['page'];
    }
    else{
        $page=1;

    }

    $all_posts_query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status='publish'";
    $all_posts_run=mysqli_query($conn,$all_posts_query);
    $all_posts=mysqli_num_rows($all_posts_run);
    $total_pages=ceil($all_posts / $no_of_posts); //ok its working for paging
    echo $posts_start_from=(2-1)*$no_of_posts;//ok working start from recent to 
    older id=2 start=2

    ?> 

<?php
                }
                $query="SELECT *FROM posts WHERE status='publish' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $posts_start_from,$no_of_posts";
                $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $date=getdate($row['date']);
                        $day=$date['mday'];
                        $month=$date['month'];
                        $year=$date['year'];
                        $title=$row['title'];
                        $author=$row['author'];
                        $author_image=$row['author_image'];
                        $image=$row['image'];
                        $categories=$row['categories'];
                        $tags=$row['tags'];
                        $post_data=$row['post_data'];
                        $views=$row['views'];
                        $status=$row['status'];

                ?>


<nav class="pagi" >
                  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mt-5">
                      <?php

                      for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)
                      {
                          echo "<li class='page-item ".($page==$i ? 'active':'')."'><a class='page-link' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a></li>";
                          }
                      ?>

                  </ul>
                </nav>
```

Url links work ok which comes from $i variable.
yryfchbcd cjdndjnn

Comment: Replace `$_Get['page']` with `$_GET['page']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ( isset($_Get['page']) ) {
    $page = $_Get['page'];
}
```

To

```
if ( isset($_GET['page']) ) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
```

I suggest using an editor or IDE with good *syntax checker* and *code completion*. Then you will avoid such mistakes easier.

Comment: will you recommend any of it to me .By the way thanks

Comment: PhpStorm is the best out of the box experienxe but paid unless you are a student. Sublime text and Atom are good too but need extensions.